# PHP ftp_connect in readonly mode

Tags: php, ftp

There is a way to establish a read-only ftp connection with PHP?

I only need to do these inside the remote ftp:

- ftp_connect
- ftp_login
- ftp_chdir
- ftp_get
- ftp_close

If I, for mistake, delete/modify something on the remote ftp it'll be a very big problem (due to work matters).

(I already check my code 10 times and do a lot of tests, but human error is always possible.)

Answer (score -1):

If you write script about FTP service, you may disable needless functions in PHP script. For disable functions, you need to change 'disable_functions' directive in php.ini context like this:

**disable_functions =ftp_put,ftp_delete,exec,passthru,**

For give additional information about PHP FTP functions, go to [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/php-ftp)

Comment: I should choose to use the readonly setting per connection not by global setting